# Azure: Publishing a web application removed my webjob on same app service

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have a Azure solution (provider web to my SharePoint app, but that shouldn't matter). I have created one app service where I publish my web application and I also have a web job which I want to have on same app service

I Deploy this web job separately by uploading the zip-file (or ps1-file) in the web job-part of my app service. Se image below
[image]

BUT: If I redeploy my web application (from Visual Studio) the web job is removed!

The best thing would be to include the web job in the deployment of the deployment of the web application, but in any case I just dont want it to be removed when I deploy the web application.

Any good solutions/suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465012/when-publishing-website-on-azure-webjobs-are-deleted

Comment: Yes you are right. But I didnt get this solution to work. I got the job published, but the schema refused to be published, I could not create a schema for a job with same name and then publish my job, as someone suggested..., nor could I create a schema after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look under the Settings tab on the Publish to Azure dialog in Visual Studio, there is a checkbox labeled "Remove Additional Files at Destination". Make sure this is unchecked. If it is checked, all additional files that are not in your Visual Studio solution will be removed.

Comment: Yes, I went for this solution. I use to have that checked, because of other problems, but in this case this worked. Thanks!